# GoogleSheet generated through the API not executing onChange Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a collection of functions in appscript that creates googlesheets from user demmand.

Some of these auto generated google sheets includes a onchange action.

These actions were working ok for all users but in some point the onchange script are not working in some users but in others are still working. The main diference between users were that only the users with permissions to edit the project can execute the script.

Finally if a sheet working with a user is shared with another that can´t execute script then the script stop working for both users.

Diving in stackdriver logging I found that when they execute this code then this error is raised:

```
{
 insertId: "vx7djue2u0fb"  
 jsonPayload: {
  message: "Se ha producido un error de servidor mientras se leía del almacenamiento. Código de error: PERMISSION_DENIED."   
  serviceContext: {
   service: "AKfycbyX--RIqp5sdZjg1-tvzuB49Su3Hv_uLYIPHL3sTMBPu1fFnfWt"
  }
 }
 labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/deployment_id: "AKfycbyX--RIqp5sdZjg1-tvzuB49Su3Hv_uLYIPHL3sTMBPu1fFnfWt"   
  script.googleapis.com/process_id: "EAEA1GOzubSNy0gOADEXYQl6P5JrPyW1LsIHSzy8rfdjbEhlaHeJQxRIkSujb2rcgf4lzR15l2zIyzmHB0hmoTdAlE8JoNvA_D1pCyYCn7_PwYjmSMizINZixww7GXyKdkzUlCAiKDEKAwvVG-RoLUTGOCUZTamGmvMJEBh4fkPPvP_RMYcP1wFPRQerKx_VBM9ZRh0HovgcnnLff-Ul8ohDCOCeR1I_Bwg0YytcIqtkZMHsbnnGBpcJvjnSO4hQ8QCmAclHJQOHNsxIQWiDzRs0vjxQcb2CGuPomu_k"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key: "MYYCOoTlQJdYUzDRb-mawTuwGdSpIyMU5"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project-id-2115762147417454578/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-02-11T09:35:57.943916689Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "sendConfirmationMail"    
   invocation_type: "unknown"    
   project_id: "project-id-2115762147417454578"    
  }
  type: "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-02-11T09:35:57.646Z"  
}
```

Has no one knows what does it mean?

Is there any chance to get help from google to know what is sayng this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: These three lines  "Mostrar entradas coincidentes
Ocultar entradas coincidentes
Añadir campo a la línea de resumen" obviously are not in the google scrippt it was a copy paste problem.

Comment: If gave read permissions in the project to the users and then the problem is solved. But it is something taht in the past was not necessary and I want to know if there is a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: When you say `this includes a onchange action` do you mean an installable trigger that occurs on change? Or is this an `onEdit()` trigger? Either way unless a user has edit permissions to a sheet they can not use triggers.